# Создать spinner в разных активити одним методом без копирования кода

Tags: java, android, ооп

Есть 2 активити где нужно заполнять спиннер одинаковыми данными. 
Заполняю так:

```
    private void loadCategories() {


    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();


    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_GET_CATEGORIES, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            try {
                JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject meta = res.getJSONObject("meta");

                // Auth OK
                if (AppController.getInstance().metaCheck(meta)) {

                    JSONObject data = res.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray categories = data.getJSONArray("categories");

                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);

                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("id", catObj.getString("id_fc"));
                        b.putString("name", catObj.getString("name"));
                        b.putInt("is_standard", catObj.getInt("standard"));
                        spinnerArray.add(b);

                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                pd.dismiss();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            AppController.getInstance().volleyOnErrorResponse(error);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();


            if (sm == null) {
                sm = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            }

            String accessToken = sm.getAccessToken();

            params.put("access_token", accessToken);

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            //HTTP Auth
            return AppController.getInstance().headerAUTH();
        }
    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);



}
```

Для каждой активити копирую один и тот же код. И потом для каждого изменения надо в обоих функциях обновить код. 
Дело в том что у меня кастомный view для спиннера. И есть кнопки например "удалить категорию". Поэтому не хочется копировать огромный код в каждую новую активити.

Вопрос в том, как инициализировать спиннер во всех активити не копируя один и тот же код?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте один класс-активити и поместите в него ваш метод из вопроса, поменяв его модификатор доступа на `protected` вместо `private`. Остальные активити расширяйте от этого нового класса, а не от обычной активити. Так у вас в каждой активити будет доступ к этомму методу и изменять его нужно будет только в одном месте. И кол-во кода в ваших активити будет меньше.